# MySQL Incorrectly Allowing Unencrypted Connections

Tags: mysql, ssl

I am trying to configure MySQL 5.1.63 so that it allows remote connections only over SSL.  I can confirm that connections work over SSL, however I can't seem to prevent unencrypted connections.

I am following the instructions from the MySQL documentation, and running the following:

```
CREATE USER 'a' IDENTIFIED BY 'a';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'a' REQUIRE SSL;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then, if "protectme" is the computer running MySQL and I run the following from a remote computer,

```
mysql -u a --password=a --host=protectme
```

it connects!  I can verify that the MySQL I am connecting to is indeed the MySQL on "protectme".  For good measure, I have tried restarting MySQL, and confirming that the user is updated in the mysql.user table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User = "a";
+------+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| Host | User | Password                                  | Select_priv | Insert_priv | Update_priv | Delete_priv | Create_priv | Drop_priv | Reload_priv | Shutdown_priv | Process_priv | File_priv | Grant_priv | References_priv | Index_priv | Alter_priv | Show_db_priv | Super_priv | Create_tmp_table_priv | Lock_tables_priv | Execute_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv | Create_view_priv | Show_view_priv | Create_routine_priv | Alter_routine_priv | Create_user_priv | Event_priv | Trigger_priv | ssl_type | ssl_cipher | x509_issuer | x509_subject | max_questions | max_updates | max_connections | max_user_connections |
+------+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| %    | a    | *667F407DE7C6AD07358FA38DAED7828A72014B4E | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y           | Y         | Y           | Y             | Y            | Y         | N          | Y               | Y          | Y          | Y            | Y          | Y                     | Y                | Y            | Y               | Y                | Y                | Y              | Y                   | Y                  | Y                | Y          | Y            | ANY      |            |             |              |             0 |           0 |               0 |                    0 |
+------+------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------+-----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+------------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Nobody else on the Internet seems to be having this problem, but it's not working at all for me!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Once connected run show status like 'Ssl_cipher';  and make sure it's nonempty. Is it?

Comment: Hi -- the value is "DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA".

Comment: Yep, you are connected via SSL, it's encrypted.

Comment: But I didn't provide any key or certificate file!

Comment: Might it be passing your client cert automatically?

Comment: There's nothing in your configuration that asks for a client certificate. You got an ordinary SSL connection where only the server certificate was sent.

Comment: Yeah @EJP is correct, I was going to say your server configuration probably isn't set to require a client certificate.

Comment: Thank you matthewnreid!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matthewnreid deserves credit for this answer.  Thank you!!

The key and certificate were provided in the mysql-client section of my my.cnf file.  You can diagnose this by looking at the ssl_cipher variable, as matthewnreid suggested.